# Dependency error on npm install (React magento)

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install React Magento 2
when I run `sudo npm install`, it shows below errors

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 1441 packages in 6.807s

93 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

Any thoughts how to remove these errors ?

Comment: Try `npm i -f`.

Comment: Server Error
FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api?_includeAppData=1 reason: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages/_app.js (67:16) @ async Function.MyApp.getInitialProps

  65 | 
  66 |   if (Component.getInitialProps) {
> 67 |     pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
     |                ^
  68 |   }
  69 | 
  70 |   return { pageProps }
Show collapsed frames

Comment: It seems that you have made a request to the server and trying to parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON. Try logging it out.